# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir ‘**’

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I test my ts code with mocha framework . When i ran command

'mocha  --exit --require ts-node/register --recursive "***/rpc.spec.ts"'

it is showing this error 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir ‘gds’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUQg6.png)

I don't know the cause of the error occur.Can somebody tell me the cause of the error and how deal with it.

I am a new developer and English is not my home language . Please forgive me if my description is not clear or the language is not used properly .

Comment: Does the `gds` directory exist? If it exists, is it reachable from where you are running the command?

Comment: gds directory doesn't exist and I have solved this error. Thank you very much for your reminder

Comment: By not providing the solution this question is useless for the community and should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a dot here:

```
mocha --exit --require ts-node/register --recursive "./**/rpc.spec.ts"
```

Also, you can set the configuration in the `package.json` file to make the command short.
You can see the configuration of mocha [here](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs).

Regards.